Kubernetes Ingress rule with Exact behaves like Prefix
I have a Kubernetes ingress configuration that uses nginx as Ingress Controller.
The Ingress template has a for loop that picks up the paths that I define in the values.yaml file as well as the type of path (Prefix or Exact) and for each adds the backend section, so in the end I end with a bunch of entries like this:
 spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
   - host: my.host
     http:
      paths:
        - backend:
           service:
             name: "my-service"
             port:
               number: <some number>
         path: /base-url/endpoint1
         pathType: Exact
        - backend:
           service:
             name: "my-service"
             port:
               number: <some number>
         path: /base-url/endpoint2
         pathType: Prefix

Problem is imagine my endpoint1 which uses Exact has subpaths, for example /base-url/endpoint1/get-something.
With the Exact matching I am expecting if I do a call to /base-url/endpoint1/get-something it would not work, but it's working, the Ingress is directing traffic to subpaths.
Does anyone know why this happens?
